# How limit focus selecting only in the specific container in android?

Tags: android, containers, setfocus

I write the android application optimized for D-Pad.
I have several containers with widgets.
The logic requires that user can select widgets in one specific container depending on application state.
I there easy way to implement this logic?

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, use View.setFocusable(boolean) for any view.  To handle all the items in the container, run through their contents like

```
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
        v.setFocusable(false);
    }
```